# What does [::1] mean in ALLOWED_HOSTS in Django?

Tags: python, django, subdomain, hosts, django-settings

I was going through the documentation for **Django's**  `ALLOWED_HOSTS` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

I came across a string `['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']` in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Everything looks fine except the `'[::1]'` part.

I can't find a realtime scenario where `'[::1]'` is used.

Can someone please explain in which use case we will use this `[::1]`

Comment: It is the localhost address for [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[::1] is the loopback address in ipv6, the equivalent would be 127.0.0.1 in ipv4.

Answer (score 2):

I know ::1 is normally used for IPv6 as localhost

Answer (score -1):

That's most important part of settings - change `ALLOWED HOSTS` when you install your project to server. The settings there must be the same as in server configuration (e.g. nginx/gunicorn), but different for debug stage on local machine.

Advice: put all crucial settings like `ALLOWED HOSTS` in another one file in terms of security.

But while you're debugging-developing on local machine - you don't really need to change `ALLOWED HOSTS`.

Comment: That's not what I was asking. What's the purpose of `[;;1]` in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: Localhost for IPv6, as stated above. But still hope my answer also will help you somehow in understanding what is it all about.